# Adjust Image on Screen while Zoom Out

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

While zooming in the Image area goes out off screen. I want it to remain fixed in place

[image]

```html
<img style="margin-bottom:-10px;width:280px;height:280px;border-adius:50%
;border:3px solid white" id="image" src="@Model.Image" /> <br />

<a id="editbutton" href="#"><i style="border:3px solid white;border-radius:80%;
 padding:12px;z-index:5000;background-color:#128edb;font-size:15px;margin-left:40%;margin-top:-200px;color:white;" class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlNOt.jpg)

Comment: Please explain what is your requirement well

Comment: Image should not go out off screen while I zoom Out

Comment: Its size should be reduced only but remain fix in its position

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in your **css** and **html** .Please check the below snippet code.

You can adjust the edit icon position with change the `right` and `bottom` value in `#editbutton` element.

```css
.imgWrap{position:relative;width:280px;height:280px;}
#editbutton{position:absolute;right:-20px;bottom:-20px}
```

```html
<div class="imgWrap">
<img style="margin-bottom:-10px;width:280px;height:280px;border-adius:50%
;border:3px solid white" id="image" src="@Model.Image" /> <br />

<a id="editbutton" href="#"><i style="border:3px solid white;border-radius:80%;
 padding:12px;background-color:#128edb;font-size:15px;color:white;" class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
 <div>
```

It will helps you. :)